# Taking books from two shelves, and picking one, probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The problem is as follows.
There are two shelves, and on the shelves are books on nature and space

On the first shelf there are ${a}$ books on nature and ${b}$ books on space.

On the second shelf there are ${c}$ books on nature and ${d}$ books on space.

A student takes two books from the first shelf and puts them on the desk, and one book  from the second shelf and puts it on the desk.
Then he takes a book from the desk.
What is the probability(${A}$) that the book he took from the desk is about nature.
Now this is a law of total probability problem, and I have solved many of these, but they all include only 1 shelf, never two separate shelves.

The usual thing I would do is set up scenarios:

H1 - Both books are on nature

H2 - 1 book is on nature , one book is space

H3 - both books are on space

--

and for shelf 2:

H4 - book is on nature

H5 - book is on space

finding the probability for these is easy.

The next step I usually do is using the total probability formula
to calculate the probability of A happening.
This is easy when there is for example only one shelf.
$${P(A) = P(H1) * P(A|H1) + P(H2) * P(A|H2) }  ...$$ and so on

However with 2 shelves influencing the result I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you work for each shelf? At which point are you stuck?

Comment: I started doing it for each shelf, and I know how to get the probability for example getting 2 books on nature, and same for the second shelf. What i'm not sure of is how do i combine these probabilities

Comment: I will suggest to edit the question, add your progress and tell us at which point you are stuck otherwise the question may get downvoted and /or closed.

Comment: Ok, I edited  it, I'm not sure what more to add, save the actual calculations which are long and aren't really the problem, they are just number crunching.

Comment: Ok so $P(3N) = P_1(2N) \times P_2(N)$. Do you see?

Comment: So you can work through this though there is a simpler way. There is $1/3$ probability that the book picked up is from shelf $2$ and $2/3$ probability that it is from shelf $1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $3$ books on the desk - $2$ are from first shelf and $1$ from second shelf. You pick one book from the desk.

Probability that you pick book from first shelf is $\dfrac{2}{3}$ and that from second shelf is $\dfrac{1}{3}$.

i) If the picked book is from the first shelf - you can pick Nature book only if both books on the desk from first shelf are nature books or one of them is nature book.

$\displaystyle P(N|1) = \dfrac{a}{a+b} \cdot \dfrac{a-1}{a+b-1} + \dfrac{1}{2}  \cdot 2 \cdot\dfrac{a}{a+b} \cdot \dfrac{b}{a+b-1}$

ii) If the picked book is from the second shelf - you can pick Nature book only if the book on the desk from second shelf is nature book.

$\displaystyle P(N|2) = \dfrac{c}{c+d}$

$P(N) = \dfrac{2}{3} \cdot P(N|1) + \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot P(N|2)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I understand, thank you for your effort. I will try to solve this and update the OP